# How to use your own Depots in Ticket to Ride Europe 1912 Expansion?

Tags: expansions, ticket-to-ride-europe

I'd like a clarification on how one uses Depots in Ticket to Ride.

Depots were introduced in the Europe 1912 Expansion pack. Here are the two rules that I'm wondering about. (Text, punctuation and formatting is from the printed English rules, numbering is mine for clarity is this question)

1. Each Time a player uses his turn to **Claim a Route** into a city with a player's Depot in it, he may pick all the Train cards from that player's Warehouse, by discarding one of his own Depots from his Warehouse back into the game box.
2. Players may pick cards from their own Warehouse, when claiming a Route into a city containing their own Depot. And players may pick cards from 2 Warehouses in a single turn, when claiming a Route that connects 2 cities each with its own Depot; to do so, they must discard 2 of their own Depots however.

Rule 1 is pretty clear but Rule 2 has me puzzled, why is the first part even there? As I read it carefully, it seems to me that the distinction in Rule 2 is that it is your own Depot and *they do not mention discarding a Depot* from your Warehouse "back into the game box."

Is that a correct interpretation? For example, if 2 players are playing, say blue and yellow. If the Yellow player empties a Blue Depot it is clear they must discard one of their Depots, but if they empty a Yellow Depot, can they avoid discarding a Depot?